# ruby-openai api gem in Ruby on Rails: how to implement a streaming conversation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openai-api, chatgpt-api

Openai provides an api which allows you to implement AI services such as ChaGPT or DAL-E.
For Ruby on Rails application, and there are couple of gems available, obe of them being `ruby-openai`.

It works very well, but the only problem is that it doesn't come with the stream conversation feature, meaning that you can only send one question request at a time without any history tracking of the conversation. In other words, the api forgets every question you asked after having sent the reply.

So how can we fix this?

Comment: The author of the `ruby-openai` has added a detailed guide on how to stream the response coming from the API. You can find it [here](https://gist.github.com/alexrudall/cb5ee1e109353ef358adb4e66631799d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to implement the whole behaviour yourself. Here are all the implementation step, including the implementation of the `dal-e` ai with a response with several pictures rather then just one.

**You can also find my whole repository **[HERE](https://github.com/OGsoundFX/ruby-open-ai)** and clone the app!!!**

## IMPLEMENTING A STREAM CONVERSATION FEATURE

### Basic implementation

Check out [Doug](https://github.com/dmbf29) Berkley's [Notion Page](https://doug-berkley.notion.site/doug-berkley/Rails-ChatGPT-Service-Object-Setup-21748fc969514b978bf6345f897b6d3e) for basic implementation of the API

### Implement a streaming conversation

By default the `openai` gem does not come with that feature, hence having to implement it yourself

1. Create your database with 3 tables (conversations, questions, answers) with thw following sctructure:

```rb
# schema.rb
ActiveRecord::Schema[7.0].define(version: 2023_05_29_194913) do
  create_table "answers", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "question_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["question_id"], name: "index_answers_on_question_id"
  end

  create_table "conversations", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "initial_question"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "historic"
  end

  create_table "questions", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "content"
    t.integer "conversation_id", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["conversation_id"], name: "index_questions_on_conversation_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "answers", "questions"
  add_foreign_key "questions", "conversations"
end
```

2. Routes

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root "pages#home" # supposes that you have a pages controller with a home action
  resources :conversations, only: [:create, :show]
  post "question", to: "conversations#ask_question"
end
```

3. Home page view (with just a button that redirects to the create conversation action -- see bellow)

```html
<h1>Let's talk</h1>
<%= button_to "Create New Conversation", conversations_path, method: :post, class: "btn btn-primary my-3" %>
```

4. Controller `app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb`

```rb
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @convo = Conversation.create
    redirect_to conversation_path(@convo)
  end

  def show
    @convo = Conversation.find(params[:id])
  end

  def ask_question
    @question = Question.new(content: params[:entry])
    conversation = Conversation.find(params[:conversation])
    @question.conversation = conversation
    @question.save
    if conversation.historic.nil?
      response = OpenaiService.new(params[:entry]).call 
      conversation.historic = "#{@question.content}\n#{response}"
    else
      response = OpenaiService.new("#{conversation.historic}\n#{params[:entry]}").call
      conversation.historic += "\n#{@question.content}\n#{response}"
    end
    conversation.save
    @answer = Answer.create(content: response, question: @question)
    redirect_to conversation_path(conversation)
  end
end
```

5. Show page `app/views/conversations/show.html.erb`

```html
<h1>This is your conversation</h1>
<p>Ask your question</p>
<form action="<%= question_path %>", method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="conversation" value="<%= @convo.id %>">
  <textarea rows="5" cols="33" name="entry"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>

<br>

<ul>
  <% @convo.questions.each do |question| %>
    <li>
      Q: <%= question.content.capitalize %> <%= "?" if question.content.strip.last != "?" %>
    </li>
    <li>
      A: <%= question.answers.first.content %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= link_to "Back", root_path %>
```

6. `rails s` and test :)

### Resources:

- https://github.com/OGsoundFX/ruby-open-ai
- https://doug-berkley.notion.site/doug-berkley/Rails-ChatGPT-Service-Object-Setup-21748fc969514b978bf6345f897b6d3e
- https://github.com/alexrudall/ruby-openai

### Going Further:

- https://gist.github.com/alexrudall/cb5ee1e109353ef358adb4e66631799d